# Using VLOOKUP in Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a compile error on this line but everything seems right to me. I need to put a vlookup inside an if statement which is making this tricky. Can someone catch the error?

```
Dim k as Integer, numS as Integer
Range(Cells(k, 13), Cells(k, 13)).Formula = _
        "=IF(" & Range(Cells(k, 14), Cells(k, 14)).Value & "=" & VLOOKUP(""Weeks from Event " & numS-1 & " to Event " & numS & """, R11C5:R10000C8, 4) & "," & (numS) & ", """")"
```

Comment: **1)** `.Formula` requires A1-notation but you're using R1C1 notation. **2)** Note from the formatting (even on this site) that `VLOOKUP` isn't inside the quotes... **3)** `Range(Cells(k, 13), Cells(k, 13))` -> `Cells(k, 13)`. Same applies to `Range(Cells(k, 14), Cells(k, 14))`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is the RC notation, try R[11]C[5]:R[10000]C[8], but to use VlookUp in VBA I like to use Application.WorksheetFunction...

```
Sub test()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim numS As Long
    Dim LookUpValue As String

    LookUpValue = "Weeks from Event " & numS - 1 & " to Event " & numS
    Debug.Print (LookUpValue)

    If (Cells(k, 14).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookUpValue, Range(Cells(11, 5), Cells(1000, 8)), 4)) Then
        Cells(k, 13).Value = numS
    Else
        Cells(k, 13).Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps. You can pull up the immediate windows (Ctrl+G) in the VBA editor to see what the value of LookUpValue will be.